# Sublist not expanding

Tags: javascript, html, css, expand

I am trying to create a simple expanding list, one of those (named "Enclosures" buttom) contains a sublist, but when trying to expand the sublist ("An article enclosure"), it doesn't expand. Here is my code:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}

var myJSON = '{ "title":"The Title of the artice","Aetype":"type","Aelink":"link","link":"Link to the artice","content":"The content of the article","enclosures":"The enclosures of the artice","authors":"The authors of the artice","publishedAt":"Article Publish Date","Stream":"Streaming the Article"}';
var myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
document.getElementById("Gparticle").innerHTML = myObj.title;
document.getElementById("Gparticle1").innerHTML = myObj.link;
document.getElementById("Gparticle2").innerHTML = myObj.content;
document.getElementById("Gparticle3").innerHTML = myObj.enclosures;
document.getElementById("Gparticle4").innerHTML = myObj.authors;
document.getElementById("Gparticle5").innerHTML = myObj.publishedAt;
document.getElementById("Gparticle6").innerHTML = myObj.Stream;
document.getElementById("Gparticle8").innerHTML = myObj.Aetype;
document.getElementById("Gparticle7").innerHTML = myObj.Aelink;
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-family: "Georgia";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: oblique;
}

p {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Georgia";
  font-style: oblique;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  box-shadow: -1em 0 0 #444;
  /* Pour ombre gauche d'une étendue de 1em */
}

button.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>


</head>

<body>

  <button class="accordion">Title</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p id="Gparticle"></p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Link</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p id="Gparticle1"></p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Content</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p id="Gparticle2"></p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Enclosures</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p id="Gparticle3"><br/>Possible Items</p>
    <p>Possible Items</p>
    <button class="accordion">An article enclosure :</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p id="Gparticle8"></p>
      <p id="Gparticle7"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Authors</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p id="Gparticle4"></p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Published At</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p id="Gparticle5"></p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Stream</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p id="Gparticle6"></p>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you're wrongly calculating `max-height` the elements are hidden because of `overflow:hidden`. Managing state of the accordion with `max-height` is terrible idea.

Comment: what would be better then ?

Comment: create a new var for the children panel to be null initially then include the height of it into the height sum.

Comment: I think the problem of `max-height`.Because in `div.panel {max-height: 0;}` .If you remove `max-height` here you can see all the list and sublists.

Comment: yes but the expanding is not working anymore

Comment: height auto and display/hide children.

Comment: can you be more clear ? with a code snippet answer